# How to Validate Date-picker in Infopath in such a way that user should select only Future Month?

Tags: infopath, validation, forms-services, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

I have Datepicker in Infopath 2013 where I need to put validation in such a way that user should select only Future Months Date. Past month dates and current month dates should not be selected. Any idea how to put Validation on Date Picker.

I tried like below :
In My Rules under Validation I have given condition like

if DatePicker < today() then in Screen tip it will show "Please select Future month"

But this code allows me to select the current month date also. Can any one suggest how to restrict the selection of current month dates.

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker <= today()  (use an equal sign)